# Centering a text within Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text, navbar

I keep failing in centering a `text` within `navbar`, and seek the rationale an my understanding.

Please find below the `syntaxes` used:

```
   <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="height: 20px;">
            <center><p class="navbar-text" style="font-size: 20px;text-align:center">test text 
             alignment</p> 
            </center><br>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

I have even tried

```
<div class="container-fluid-nav text-center">
```

without any improvement.

*N.B : Feedback leveraging on `Bootstrap` version `3.4.1` would highly be appreciated.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your bootstrap version?

Comment: @AmirMaghami: version ```3.4.1```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `.navbar-text` has `float: left` property in `min-width: 768px`.
So you can set it `none` in `style`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse justify-content-center navbar-fixed-top" style=""><p class="navbar-text text-center" style="font-size: 20px; float: none;">test text alignment</p>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Although I have been using ```boostrap_v_3.4.1``` I was expecting the same outcome like you. Something else, from my side, may thus prevent the ```text``` from being centered after amending the adequate tag(s).

Comment: I am inferring a version issue since your suggestion works well in Bootstrap version 4.3.1 as opposed to version 3.4.1.

Comment: Yes, how about using version 5.x?

Comment: Slight side effects in migrating to newer versions (>= 4.3.1) : generation of unforeseen  and marginal issues on the interface. Reason why I have kept using version 3.4.1.

Comment: Then, how about using `w-100 text-center` class p tag?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? do you mean to add <p class="w-100"> or in conjunction with "navbar-text"?

Comment: As you can see, navbar-text has `display: inline-block;` so cannot show your expected result. I will edit my answer to give some options, and you can use any one of them.

Comment: Highly appreciated, @Sato Takeru. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239426/discussion-between-sato-takeru-and-dark-vador).

Comment: Thanks indeed for the chat conversation, as well as your latest post.

Comment: You are welcome. All people here are helping others. :)